# Access nested xml with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm trying to parse XML with jQuery as a newbie.

The XML may or may not be malformed (and I would love to know if it were so that I can feed back), but either way I don't have control over it to change its format.

Here's the XML:

[image]

By using the following I'm able to access all of the text of "max":

```
var max = $( this ).find( "max" ).text();
```

(Where $(this) refers to a higher level node). However, this results in: 11.0010.001.00

I'm simply trying to get the figure directly below "max" - in this case, 11.00.

How can I do this, and is this XML correctly formatted?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

"11.00" has no markup therefore it's not well formed
you could use

```
<max value="11.00">
```

or

```
<value>"11.00"</value>
```

it depends what you use, how you can access it

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have control over the XML to reformat it.

Comment: odd, something you don't have control of should generate valid xml...good luck